# Why is SAS converting character to numeric?

Tags: formatting, sas, format

I'm build/have built a process for a team in the company I work for. However, I keep seeing this note whenever I run part of my code. SAS Seems to be converting my character values to numeric and it's bugging. It doesn't seem to be causing any apparent issues with my data...but I would like to know why, and solve this issue if I can. here's a snippet of the code from my log:

```
MPRINT(CFPB):   DATA trunc;
MPRINT(CFPB):   SET eq_final;
MPRINT(CFPB):   Acct_Num=SUBSTR(Acct_Numb,7,4);
MPRINT(CFPB):   Source = "Eq";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "1" or "01" THEN Acct_Description = "Unsecured";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "0" or "00" THEN Acct_Description = "AutoOnly";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "2" or "02" THEN Acct_Description = "AutoOther";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "6D" THEN Acct_Description = "HELON";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "89" THEN Acct_Description = "HELOC";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "0G" THEN Acct_Description = "FlexSpending";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Acct_Type = "18" THEN Acct_Description = "CrCard";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF inputAssocCode not =: "W" AND Error_Description not =: "A1/J1" OR "A2/J2";
MPRINT(CFPB):   IF Error_Description not =: "No Error";
MPRINT(CFPB):   DROP Acct_Numb ;
MPRINT(CFPB):   RUN;

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by:
      (Line):(Column).
      33:113   33:185   34:2     36:118
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, 'A2/J2' , at line 36 column 118.
BASE_CIS_ID=00000123456
Error_Description=A2/J2 Last Name is Missing or Invalid ACCT_Type=6D inputAssocCode=W
Acct_Num=1234 Source=Equifax Acct_Description=HELON _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, 'A2/J2' , at line 36 column 118.
BASE_CIS_ID=00000234567 Error_Description=A2/J2 First Name is Missing Invalid
ACCT_Type=00 inputAssocCode=W Acct_Num=2345 Source=Equifax Acct_Description=AutoOther _ERROR_=1
_N_=3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with this section of your code and the other similar sections:

```
 IF Acct_Type = "1" or "01" then ...
 IF inputAssocCode not =: "W" AND Error_Description not =: "A1/J1" OR "A2/J2";
```

Due to SAS operator precedence, this is equvalent to:

```
 IF (Acct_Type = "1") or "01" then ...
 IF inputAssocCode not =: "W" AND Error_Description (not =: "A1/J1") OR "A2/J2";
```

SAS will attempt to interpret the character literals "01" and "A2/J2" as logical values because they're being used next to an `or` operator, which involves converting them to numeric first.

You should use the `in` operator instead, e.g.

```
 IF Acct_Type in ("1","01") then ...
 IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND not (Error_Description in: ("A1/J1","A2/J2"));
```

Comment: I see... that makes sense, but does "ne:" and "in:" work the same as "not =:". I need these arguments to be "LIKE" not exact matches..

Comment: Yes, the colon modifier allows partial matches from the start of the string.

Comment: Also, what does this mean if you're using an OR operator with just character strings.
ex: `IF inputAssocCode not =: "W" AND Error_Description (not =: "A/J") OR "A/J";`

Comment: SAS tries to treat them as logical values and fails if they don't look like numbers, leading to the note about `Invalid numeric data`.

Comment: So how do you compare character strings, using the in function?

ex: `IF acct_type in ("HE", "VEH") then acct_desc = 1;`?

Comment: Also, why use a comma and not `OR` here:

`IF Acct_Type in ("1","01") THEN Acct_Description = "Unsecured";`

but we do here

`IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND NOT Error_Description in: ("A1/J1" OR "A2/J2");`

This doesn't seem consistent.. both the first and second arguments have a numeric value in them, but with the first we use in `("1", "01")` and not `("1" OR "01")`

Comment: Sorry, I should have used a comma both times. Corrected now!

Comment: Ok, just a heads up, SAS will NOT accept that argument with an `OR` operator.

Comment: also, the position of `NOT` shouldn't matter right, for readability purposes, I switched my code to:

`IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND Error_Description NOT in: ("A1/J1","A2/J2");`

instead of:
`IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND NOT Error_Description in: ("A1/J1","A2/J2");`

Comment: If you want to move the NOT then you need to add (). `NOT X in (a,b)` will evaluate X as a logical and see if the result is in the list of values.  You would want `NOT (x in (a,b))` instead.

Comment: Tom, you're saying `IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND Error_Description NOT in: ("A1/J1","A2/J2");` would look for Error_description in `"A1/J1","A2/J2"`? Does this mean the `IN` function allows the values in quotes, or (), to be variables? otherwise that doesn't make sense to me...
the way you have it written, that still wouldn't move the `NOT` for readability purpose, rather just restructuring the code:
`IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND NOT Error_Description in: ("A1/J1","A2/J2");` vs `IF inputAssocCode ne: "W" AND NOT (Error_Description  IN: ("A1/J1","A2/J2"));`

Comment: I was saying be careful in placement of the NOT because without the () to tell SAS how to group it could apply the NOT to the wrong value and  you could get the same problem as in the original question.    The syntax for the IN operator requires a list of one or more values inside (). If the value being tested is character then the values are character literals and so they will need to be in quotes.  If the value being tested is a number then you don't want quotes around the numeric literal values in the list.